# How do I change Google Docs default quotation symbols

Tags: google-docs

Default quotation symbols in Google Docs are curly ones  “”. I would like to use command line quotes like "". I can't find any solution except:

> Insert -> Special Characters -> Punctuation -> Quotation Mark

Is it possible to change default quotation symbols in Google Docs?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

At the top of Tools > Preferences:

[image: WA63237 example]

Comment: dam... I was looking for this for too long, thanks!

Comment: "smart quotes" were not so smart after all.

Answer (score 4):

The smart quotes are kind of automatic replacement. You can undo every automatic replacement with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Example:
Type <kbd>"</kbd>: Google Docs will replace by `“`
Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>: Google Docs will undo the replacement and leave `"`

Answer (score -3):

Go to Settings -> Input Methods to change it.